# Android toast message "Background update service is running (with intent)"

Tags: android, android-intent

just got my new samsung s8+ android phone. It updated itself and there is a toast message warning display in every 30 minutes, its writing "Background update service is running (with intent)". So what is the cause of it, there are no apps 
 installed can do that. Its very annoying, how can i turn it off?

Comment: connect your mobile with android studio and give us logcat screenshots when the toast gets visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure it out. That message comes from "Plesk Server App". That app is sending toast messages like every 30 min.

Comment: Hard to believe that Samsung ships it's phones with "Plesk Server App".

Comment: Nope i just installed that app first. I didnt know it cause that.

Answer (score 0):

This has something with you needing to use the latest Beta. Have a link at this link and just translate with google to understand the language. https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/background-update-service-is-running-with-intent.892816/